# Formatting Floating Point Numbers

Tags: java, string, floating-point, double, string-formatting

I have a variable of type `double`, I need to print it in upto 3 decimals of precision but it shouldn't have any trailing zeros...

eg. I need

```
2.5 // not 2.500
2   // not 2.000
1.375 // exactly till 3 decimals
2.12  // not 2.120
```

I tried using `DecimalFormatter`, Am i doing it wrong?

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
myFormatter.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try the pattern `"0.###"` instead of `"0.000"`:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
        double[] tests = {2.50, 2.0, 1.3751212, 2.1200};
        for(double d : tests) {
            System.out.println(df.format(d));
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
2.5
2
1.375
2.12
```

Answer (score 6):

Your solution is almost correct, but you should replace zeros '0' in decimal format pattern by hashes "#".

So it should look like this:

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
```

And that line is not necesary (as `decimalSeparatorAlwaysShown` is `false` by default):

```
myFormatter.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
```

Here is short summary from javadocs:

```
Symbol  Location    Localized?  Meaning
0   Number  Yes Digit
#   Number  Yes Digit, zero shows as absent
```

And the link to javadoc: [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use NumberFormat class.

Example:

> ```
>     double d = 2.5;
>     NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getInstance();
>     n.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
>     System.out.println(n.format(d));
> ```

Output will be 2.5, not 2.500.