# Android Distance Between

Tags: c#, android, location, monodevelop, valueconverter

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and have a distance between two points. What is the value returned measured in?

Here is the code that I use:

```
    Location.DistanceBetween(startLat, startLng, endLat, endLng, distResults);
```

And more importantly, how can I convert this value into meters and Kilometers if needed?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I am getting the following value returned from the function: 74 4760445. Is this 74 meters? What are the other digits after the 74? From this value, how can I just get 74? With no other values?

Answer (score 1):

```
distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```

Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them.

check this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: the number is an array of floats to hold the results of the distance because its an approximate distance in meters between two locations.

Comment: and If u want the result to in a specific format you can check this    http://stackoverflow.com/a/4733118/1838457

Comment: The distResults[0] contains the value: 74 4760445. Is this 74 meters? What are the trailing values of 4760445? Is the distance 74.4760445 meters?

Comment: So in the above example, the distance is 74.4760445 meters? Is that correct?