# How to print up to 2 digits after the decimal point?

Tags: java

i have a small problem with printing format.
i want to print 2 digits after the decimal point if the number
is not an integer (for example 55.53467 -> 55.53) and 1 digit after the decimal
point if the number is integer or has a round number after the decimal point (for
example 2.00 -> 2.0 or 5.10 -> 5.1).

the piece of code that i have is:

```
public String toString() {

    return String.format("%+.2f%+.2fX%+.2fX^2%+.2fX^3%+.2fx^4", this.A0.getCoefficient()
                                                              , this.A1.getCoefficient()
                                                              , this.A2.getCoefficient()
                                                              , this.A3.getCoefficient()
                                                              , this.A4.getCoefficient());
}
```

but it always prints 2 digits of course.
thanks a lot

Comment: "it always prints two digits of course." Then change it. Use `if`/`else` logic.

Comment: why? why not just say 2.00 as well, to keep things uniform? If the argument is "the second zero does not add anything", then sure but neither does the first one. If you want to show a formula, "2x + 4.3y" makes sense, "2.0x + 4.3y" does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Floating Point Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733089/formatting-floating-point-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take advantage of DecimalFormat, for example:

```
public static String format(double num, double places) {
    String format = "#.";
    for(int i=0; i<places; i++) format += "0";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(format);
    return df.format((int)(num * Math.pow(10, places)) / (double) Math.pow(10, places));
}
```

Then you may use it to any decimal place:

```
System.out.println(format(1, 2)); // 1.00
System.out.println(format(234, 2)); // 234.00
System.out.println(format(-55.12345, 2)); // -55.12
System.out.println(format(7.2, 2)); // 7.20
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would format the floats with DecimalFormat "0.0#" (# says: only set if not zero) to String-Vars and pass the results to function String.format.